# How to make a regex case sensitive

Tags: regex, shell

I have a below regex and want that it only accepts case sensitive chars, what should i change it to

```html
msg_regex='ABC-[0-9]+|DEF-[0-9]+|GHI-[0-9]+'
```

Its used in the below shell script  :-

```html
#!/bin/bash
set -e

zero_commit='0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
msg_regex='ABC-[0-9]+|DEF-[0-9]+|GHE-[0-9]+'

while read -r oldrev newrev refname; do

 # Branch or tag got deleted, ignore the push
    [ "$newrev" = "$zero_commit" ] && continue

    # Calculate range for new branch/updated branch
    [ "$oldrev" = "$zero_commit" ] && range="$newrev" || range="$oldrev..$newrev"

 for commit in $(git rev-list "$range" --not --all); do
  if ! git log --max-count=1 --format=%B $commit | grep -iqE "$msg_regex"; then
   echo "ERROR:"
   echo "ERROR: Your push was rejected because the commit"
   echo "ERROR: $commit in ${refname#refs/heads/}"
   echo "ERROR: is missing the JIRA Issue"
   echo "ERROR:"
   echo "ERROR: Please fix the commit message and push again."
   echo "ERROR: https://confluence.ameren.com/display/PUBLIC/Checking+Commit+Message+For+JIRA+Issue+Number"
   echo "ERROR"
   exit 1
  fi
 done

done
```

Looks like the grep in the below is ignoring the case :-

```html
if ! git log --max-count=1 --format=%B $commit | grep -iqE "$msg_regex"
```

Right now it gets evaluated for lower case abc, def and ghi also.

I would like that it only allows ABC, DEF and GHI uppercase but at the same be able to accept any number from 0 to infinite in the format ABC-number or DEF-number or GHI-number

Please suggest!

Comment: Where is it used and how? This is just a pattern, what flags/options do  you use, what is the method/language?

Comment: In most environments regular expressions are case-sensitive by default, you need to use additional options to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Just edited the questions. thanks folks!

Comment: Don't use the `-i` option to `grep`, that makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: Why do you use the `-i` option if you don't want that? Did you forget what it means?

Comment: Ah! You are correct Barmar. I completely missed that. I have corrected that now in my script and it works fine. Thanks for the prompt help